# Script won't save images

Tags: php

For some reason my script always returns an echo when uploading a file.
My form:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class='makePost' action="post.php" method="post">
  <label for="title">Kies een titel voor uw post: </label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Titel" />

  <label for="tags">Voeg tags toe aan uw post: </label>
  <input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" placeholder="Tags - Gebruik een '&#45;' om tags te onderscheiden." />

  <label for="post">Maak hier uw post: </label>
  <p><em>Gebruik **(text)** om tekst vetgedrukt te maken. Gebruik --(tekst)-- om tekst schuingedrukt te maken en gebruik ^^(titel)^^ voor titels en headers.</em></p>
  <textarea name="post" rows="50" cols="90" placeholder="Maak hier uw post."></textarea>

  <label for="editors">Kies anderen die uw post mogen bewerken: </label>
  <select class="editors" name="editors" id="editors">
    <?php
      echo "<option value='1'>editName</option>";
      echo "<option value='2'>editName</option>";
      echo "<option value='3'>editName</option>";
      echo "<option value='4'>editName</option>";
    ?>
  </select>
  <label for="thumbnail">Upload een thumbnail voor uw post: </label>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
  <label for="post">Post klaar? Gecheckt op fouten? Post hem nu! </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Post" name="post" id="post" />

</form>
```

And my PHP (Which is in the same file):

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['userType'])){
      $userType = $_SESSION['userType'];
      if($userType === 'editor' || $userType === 'admin') {
        $error = 1;
        if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
          $title      = htmlentities($_POST['title']);
          $tags       = htmlentities($_POST['tags']);
          $post       = htmlentities($_POST['post']);
          $editors    = htmlentities($_POST['editors']);
          $author     = htmlentities($_SESSION['userID']);
          // $thumbnail  = htmlentities($_POST['thumbnail']);

          $target_dir    = "uploads/";
          $target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
          $uploadOk      = 1;
          $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

          if(isset($_POST['post'])){
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
              $log     .= 'File is not an image. Please try again.<br/>';
              $uploadOk = 0;
            }
          }
          if(file_exists($target_file)) {
            $log     .= "Sorry, a file with this name already exists. Please try renaming the file.<br/>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
          }
          if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            $log     .= "Sorry, your file is too large. We only support images up to 500kb.<br/>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
          }
          if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG"){
            $log .= "Sorry we only support files of types .jpg, .jpeg and .png files<br/>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
          }
          if($uploadOk == 0) {
            $log .= 'Sorry, for some reason your file was not uploaded<br/>';
          } else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
              $log .= "Photo uploaded!";
              $thumbnail = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
              $error = 0;
              $log .= $thumbnail."<br/>";
            } else {
              $log .= "Sorry there was an error while uploading<br/>";
            }
          }

          if($error == 0) {
            $postArr = $arrayName = array(
              'title'     => $title,
              'tags'      => $tags,
              'post'      => $post,
              'author'    => $author,
              'editors'   => $editors,
              'thumbnail' => $thumbnail
            );

            $post = new Post(false, $postArr);
            $post->sendPost();
          }
        }

        $views = "views/post.php";
      }
    } else {
      $log .= 'Unfortunately your account is not allowed to post, if you think you should be: contact an administrator.<br />';
    }
  } else {
    $log .= 'Unfortunately your account is not allowed to post, if you think you should be: contact an administrator.<br />';
  }
  /*End logic code*/

  include_once $template;

?>
```

So all I want is to save the inputted image to my directory. The error message that is returned:

> Post
>   File is not an image. Please try again.
>   Sorry, for some reason your file was not uploaded

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First please check the error message which you got its not in code.

Comment: I got an error message generated by my code. But I don't understand why it is an error.

Comment: Don't simply auto generate your own errors. Use the try catch block to manipulate exceptions, you will have a better understanding on what is happening.

Comment: What function is `getimagesize`? Seems to be broken...

Comment: @PhiterFernandes In this case there aren't errors: it's merely server-side validation, not error handling. A try-catch will not help determining the file type or size (and if If an error is thrown, it will be shown anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc for [`getimagesize`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

> On failure, **FALSE** is returned.

In this section of your code, you're checking for `getimagesize` to *not return false*. I think you mean to check for it to be *equal to false*, instead, because you're checking for *failure*.

```
if(isset($_POST['post'])){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) { // Here. Should be ===, not !==. Alternatively, `!$check`
        $log     .= 'File is not an image. Please try again.<br/>';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!
Struggled with this all day.
This solved the problem, also a hint for me to check the documentation a little more!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your check is the reverse of what you want

You have

```
if($check !== false) {
```

But, it should be

```
if(!$check) {
```